# Find the area of the parallelogram with vertices $(4,1)$, $(6, 6)$, $(7, 7)$, and $(9, 12)$.

Tags: vector-spaces, plane-curves, area

I am trying to find the area of the parallelogram with vertices $(4,1)$, $(6, 6)$, $(7, 7)$, and $(9, 12)$.

So I believe the way to solve this problem is through the cross product and then taking the magnitude. However, I got the wrong answer and I am now rethinking my methods.

My original work:

Point $A$: $(4,1)$;
Point $B$: $(6,6)$;
Point $C$: $(7,7)$;
Point $D$: $(9,12)$.

I took the cross product of $\vec{AB}$ and $\vec{AC}$ and took the magnitude of that and ended up getting $\sqrt{369}$.

I would appreciate the help. I am kind of stumped.

Comment: Probably AB or AC is a _diagonal_ rather than a _side_. Draw a picture and see, otherwise your approach is good and the error is just an arithmetic mistake.

Comment: I drew it multiple times on a large paper and it was still very ambiguous. I am not sure if I am taking the right points...?

Comment: The cross product is much shorter than you have calculated.  Did you subtract all the components of A from B to get the vector AB?  Please show how you got $\sqrt {369}$  It is true that neither AB nor AC is a diagonal.

Answer (score 1):

See this [illustration](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~ronmiech/Calculus_Problems/32A/chap11/section4/708d19/708_19.html) on how to compute the area of a parallelogram in an easy manner.

Comment: That's actually how I got this far I looked at the page; however, I am not sure why my setup is wrong

Answer (score 0):

area should be 3 square units.

Comment: Why?${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: AB=2i+5j, AC=3i+6j. So, AB x AC=-3k. Area- magnitude= 3 sq. units.

Comment: İf you explained a little I would have upvoted the answer.